# Problems simulating click of ASP.NET button

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have some code like this

```
<asp:Button ID="cancelDummyButt" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
    Text="cancel" onclick="cancelDummyButt_Click" Enabled="True" />
```

(Javascript:)

```
buttid = '<%=cancelDummyButt.ClientID.ToString%>';
eltoclick = document.getElementById(buttid);
eltoclick.click();
```

The server-side code is not called.  What is wrong?  It goes OK until the "click". What is the best way to debug?

*(This is to get the right postback from an iframe within an updatepanel)*

Comment: remove the tostring and it works! (and maybe 'OnClick' instead of 'onclick')

Answer (score 1):

Olav, the trick with the modal windows is to have a hidden ASP:Button *outside* the modal window. You can have a regular html button inside the modal window that when clicked on, calls the __doPostback('', '') method for the hidden ASP:Button control. This has the same effect as actually clicking the ASP button.

```
<!-- start modal dialog div -->

   <input type="button" onclick="__doPostBack('<%= btnDoIt.UniqueID %>','');" value="Do It!" />

<!-- end modal dialog div -->

<asp:Button id="btnDoIt" style="display:none;" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically invoking the click() event of a control does **not** fire the event handler function.  You'll need to invoke it manually....

```
if(eltoclick.onclick())
  eltoclick.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a mistake in this line :

```
buttid = '<%= cancelDummyButt.ClientID.ToString() %>';
```

my recommendation is that, place your javascript code to code behind and then register to page like that :

```
string script = string.Format("var buttid = '{0}';", cancelDummyButt.ClientID);
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("myScript"))
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(_Default), "myScript", script, true);
}
```

Comment: I think ToString without "()" is ok in VB.NET - anyway buttid and eltoclick got assigned correctly, as far as i could see

Answer (score 0):

Solved - it was cause by a modal jQuerywindow!

(Would like some way around that, of course)

Olav